# HOw To call Function (View view) Values with in the braces in android

Tags: android, function, view, text-to-speech, toast

```
 String toSpeak=null;    

 public void speakText(View view){

    //String toSpeak = write.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

}
```

And i am calling like this

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receive_payment);

    toSpeak="Hello Mr Prawin";
   speakText();

}
```

> why because i want to call this function On load Layout Event

Comment: Are you asking what to put in for the `param` of `speakText()`? If so, use `this` in that situation. That refers to your `Activity Context`. And you might want to [read this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.doubleencore.com%2F2013%2F06%2Fcontext%2F&ei=4nH7U9TVCcn8yQTI64CYBg&usg=AFQjCNEQHYljsmkUjnhhgr2Wyq8534_wxw&sig2=fUVbsmsEpeTjy8LAJHBVUw&bvm=bv.73612305,d.aWw)

Comment: On load Page I am Calling TextToSpeach Function with My Self Generated Text Pls Help Me

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context by invoking `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()` or `this` (when in the activity class).

So pass `this` as actvity context in your function as

```
 speakText(this);
```

For more info see [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

**Edit**

you want `speakText` on button click so add   `android:onClick="speakText"` under button tag in your xml layout as

```
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:onClick="speakText" />
```

And remove `speakText();` from  `onCreate` method.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Happy to help,enjoy.

Comment: Giri Bhai See my Question Once Again,and Give me the Solution

Comment: @PraveenKumar where did you use `view` in your function?

Comment: public void speakText(View view)

Comment: public void speakText(View view) with out View I am unable to call    ttobj.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

Comment: @PraveenKumar where did you initialize `ttobj`

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm   My Code Base from that site

Comment: Friend My Question is with out Button Click Call function

Comment: @PraveenKumar add  `android:onClick="speakText"` in your xml,see updated answer.

Comment: Giru Bayya Actually that is the basic Script, my Requirement is with out Clicking  i want to call that Function Tnx

Comment: @PraveenKumar then remove `View view` from your function.And also remove `android:onClick="speakText"`

Answer (score 0):

What I can see that, speakTest method is your own method, and you are not using the view object in your method. Then why don't you just remove view parameter from your method. If you can not for some reason then simply pass null for view because view is not being used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I Got Solution 
public class Receive_Payment extends Activity implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {  // I am Calling From Here
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   {
     * **  Somthing
             text="Hello Prawin";
              speakOut()
   }

public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

    @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        //int result=tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hin"));
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result ==         

      TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
           // btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

}

private void speakOut() {

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
}
```